# Como fazer if nao repetir a função para quem já atingiu um numero

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Eu faço uma chamada no BD pela API para ver os dados de porcentagem de vendas das filiais de uma loja, e se caso a porcentagem seja maior ou igual a 100% eu devo tocar uma musica e mudar a cor dela pra verde.

E eu uso o schedule ***(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)*** para ficar recarregando o conteúdo.

Só que toda vez que o conteúdo é recarregado ele toca de novo a música para a filial que ja atingiu a meta, sendo que só é pra tocar a música apenas uma vez para a filial, tem que tocar de novo se outra filial atingir a meta.

Método que lista as filiais, muda de cor, toca música e porcentagem delas:

```
 ListaFiliaisDiaria() {

    this.MetaService.FiliaisMetaDiarias().subscribe(
      data => {
        const response = (data as any)
        this.objeto_retorno = JSON.parse(response._body);

        this.fil.length = 0;
        this.filMetade.length = 0
        this.filNaoAtingida.length = 0

        this.objeto_retorno.forEach(element => {

          this.tots = element.TOTAL
          element.TOTAL = (element.TOTAL * 100).toFixed(3) + '%'
          element.TOTAL = element.TOTAL.toString().replace(".", ",")


          if (this.tots >= this.MetaAtingida) {

            this.audio = new Audio();
            this.audio.src = "../../../assets/music/SupermanCorrect.mp3";
            this.audio.load();
            this.audio.play();

            this.fil.push({
              FI: element.FILIAL,
              porc: element.TOTAL             
            });

            this.mainColor = 'MetaAtingida'          

          }
          else if (this.tots >= this.MetaMetade && this.tots < this.MetaAtingida) {

            this.filMetade.push({
              filialMetade: element.FILIAL,
              porcMetade: element.TOTAL
            });

            this.mainColorTwo = 'MetaOitenta'

          }

          else if (this.tots < this.MetaMetade) {

            this.filNaoAtingida.push({
              FilialNaoAtingida: element.FILIAL,
              MetaNaoAtingida: element.TOTAL
            });
            this.mainColorThree = 'MetaNaoAtingida'

          }

        })

      }
}
```

e no ngOnInit():

```
  ngOnInit() {
    schedule.scheduleJob(' 15 * * * * * ', () => {         
      this.ListaFiliaisDiaria()
    });
}
```

o HTML que lista as filiais:

```
<p [class]="mainColor + ' teste' " *ngFor="let element of fil" id="fi">Filial {{ element.FI }} = {{ element.porc }}</p>

<p [class]="mainColorTwo + ' teste' " *ngFor="let element of filMetade">Filial {{ element.filialMetade }} = {{ element.porcMetade }}</p>

<p [class]="mainColorThree + ' teste '" *ngFor="let element of filNaoAtingida">Filial {{ element.FilialNaoAtingida }} = {{ element.MetaNaoAtingida }}</p>
```

**Como consigo colocar pra tocar apenas uma vez a música para aquela filial? Alguém pode me ajudar?**

Comment: Seria um código mais limpo separar a parte que toca a musica em outra função. Basicamente vc tem que comparar seu estado antigo com o novo e tocar somente se alguma que ja não tinha batido a meta agora tiver batido.

Comment: Mas como vou comparar o antigo com o novo?

Comment: Tem varias formas a mais fácil seria salvar o resultado do response numa propriedade desse seu componente.  Ai cada nova requisição vc compara com essa propriedade e no fim seta ela pro valor da nova requisição.